# Excel Macro to Search Single Worksheet for List containing Approx 30 numbers of strings each with eight characters

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have a list of approximately 30, eight character strings (ex. "BOFAUS3N") that I want to use as a search list for a spreadsheet of wire transfer data.  I'd like the search to be conducted on all cells with results added to one of three tabs.

Example(Assuming searched data is on Tab 1):

```
BOFAUS3N, BOFAUS6S, etc. on Tab 2 
BOFAUS3M,           etc. on Tab 3
BOFAUS3D,           etc. on Tab 4
```

I'm not very familiar with VBA, so any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You might get what you are looking for using the VLOOKUP function built into Excel.

If not familiar with it, you select a sorted set of keys (search values) make sure  you have both $s in the range because you don't want it to change.  Then you select the range you are searching over, give it the index of whatever column from that range you want to return, and a flag for exact match which you want in this case.

You would use this method only highlighting the keys you want related to each tab.

[Office Reference](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1)